# Applescript: How to click a NON-default button in an Untitled dialog?

Tags: applescript, itunes

Specifically, I'm trying to click the "Create Library" button in iTunes option-launch dialog. The "Choose Library" button is the default. Furthermore, pressing tab has no effect when navigating the dialog by hand.

Comment: Did you use the Accessibility Inspector to find out what that button is?

Comment: What do you mean by "what the button is"? and how do I do that?

Comment: Really? Okay: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40436/how-to-know-the-name-of-ui-elements-using-accessibility-inspector-or-any-other